# Open another ejs file in button ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have an index.ejs file in my NodeJS application. Inside index.ejs file, I want to use a button to open another ejs file with code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick='register.ejs'>Register</button>
```

But when I run application, when I hit that button, it totally return nothing else this error:

```
Cannot GET /register.ejs
```

I even put register.ejs in the same folder with index.ejs but it still not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*.ejs files are template files, not static files. So you can't call them by their filename. 
to make your 'register' working first create a path to register.ejs file in route file

```
router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
  res.render('path/to/ejs/files/register');
});
```

then change your button link to /register